# What is the best way to store daily prices on Apache Druid?

Tags: aggregation, druid

I'd like to store daily prices on Apache Druid in a way that is possible to group it by daily, weekly and monthly. I was thinking of defining open and close prices as metrics, not dimensions, but for that I would have to use first and last aggregators to group open and close prices, respectively. The [documentation](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/aggregations.html#first--last-aggregator) says:

> (Double/Float/Long) First and Last aggregator cannot be used in ingestion spec, and should only be specified as part of queries.

So it seems I cannot load the data in this way already. I would like to know what would be the best way to load daily prices data in a way that allows me to use all of druid's capabilities when grouping by day, week or month.

Comment: Could you give some more information, maybe an example as what you expect to receive?